# Getting Sprite Co-Ordinates in Crafty.js

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, craftyjs

Im trying to get the co-ordinates of where my player character is standing so when they come back from 'battle' they will be standing where they were before they started, However Im using the fourway function that comes with crafty.js so I cant see any of the variables in use, is there a way I can or will I have to make my own movement events?

Here is my code:

```
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1', function () {
Location = 3;

Crafty.e('2RoomCorridor');
//Draw Entites in the game world
//Drawing Other Entities
Crafty.e('Borders');
//
//Temporary dirty fix, need to find way to store player co-ordinates
//

if (monsterBeat == false)
{
Crafty.e('Enemy').at(22, 10);
Crafty.e('Player').at(PlayerX, PlayerY);
}
else
{
Crafty.e('Player').at(22,10);
}

Crafty.e('TeleporterYR10TP1_1').at(16,1);
});

    Crafty.c('Player', {
init: function(){
this.requires('Actor, Color, Fourway, Collision, spr_player, SpriteAnimation,    Keyboard')

.color('none')
.fourway(3)
.stopOnSolids()
.onHit('NPC1Event', this.Level2)
.onHit('Enemy', this.attackEnemy)
.onHit('TeleporterHubWorld', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterSpawn', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP1', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP1_1', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP1_1.1', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP1_1.2', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP2', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR10TP3', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR11TP1', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR11TP2', this.Level2)
.onHit('TeleporterYR11TP3', this.Level2)
.animate('PlayerUp', 0, 0, 3)
.animate('PlayerDown', 0, 1, 3)
.animate('PlayerRight', 0, 2, 3)
.animate('PlayerLeft', 0, 3, 3)
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('SPACE')) Crafty.scene('World'); })
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('F')) Crafty.scene('BattleScreen'); });

// this makes the Sprite animate on player input, need to analyse before I complete
var animation_speed = 10;
this.bind('NewDirection', function(data) {
  if (data.x > 0) {
    this.animate('PlayerRight', animation_speed, -1);
  } else if (data.x < 0) {
    this.animate('PlayerLeft', animation_speed, -1);
  } else if (data.y > 0) {
    this.animate('PlayerUp', animation_speed, -1);
  } else if (data.y < 0) {
    this.animate('PlayerDown', animation_speed, -1);
  } else {
    this.stop();
  }
});
},

stopOnSolids: function() {
 this.onHit('Solid', this.stopMovement);

 return this;
},

attackEnemy: function(data) {
Enemy = data[0].obj;
Enemy.collect();
},

Level2: function(data) {
Teleporter1 = data[0].obj;
Teleporter1.collect();
monsterBeat = false;
},

Crafty.c('BattlePlayer', {
init:function() {
var MenuPos = 1;
var HealthPas = 100 + ',' + 100;
//Displays options for the first time with attack selected

this.requires('Actor, Color, spr_BattlePlayer, SpriteAnimation, Keyboard')
.color('none')
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('SPACE')) Crafty.scene('World'); })
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('ENTER')) HealthPas = this.BattleSelect(MenuPos, HealthPas);})
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('S')) if (MenuPos < 3){MenuPos = MenuPos + 1}; this.MenuMove(MenuPos); })
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('W')) if (MenuPos > 1) {MenuPos = MenuPos - 1}; this.MenuMove(MenuPos); });

Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 500 })
.text('N/A');

Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 150 })
.text(100);

Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 100 })
.text(100);

Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);

var MenuPos = 1;    

},
//function for displaying what option is currently selected
MenuMove: function(MenuPos) {
switch (MenuPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 500 })
.text('N/A');
break;

case 2:
//Defend case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendSel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 500 })
.text('N/A');
break;

case 3:
//Run case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunSel').at(3,18);
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 500 })
.text('N/A');
break;

default:
//Incorrect input case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);

Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 500 })
.text('N/A')
.textColor('#FF0000');
}
},

//function for carrying out battle options
//Within this function Num[0] represents players health and Nums[1] represents the  Enemy Health.
BattleSelect: function(MenuPos, HealthPas) {
var Nums = HealthPas.split(',');
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 150 })
.text(Nums[0]);

switch (MenuPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
Nums[1] = Nums[1] - 20;
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 100 })
.text(Nums[1]);
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10;
break;

case 2:
//Heal case
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 1 + 21;
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
break;

case 3:
//Run case
//switch checks what room the player is in the transport them back there
switch (Location)
{
case 1:
Crafty.scene('World');
break;

case 2:
Crafty.scene('HubWorld');
break;

case 3:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1');
break;

case 4:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp2');
break;

case 5:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp3');
break;

case 6:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp1');
break;

case 7:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp2');
break;

case 8:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp3');
break;

default:
Crafty.scene('World');
}

default:
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10;
}
HealthPas = Nums[0] + ',' + Nums[1];
return HealthPas;
},

//function to check for winning conditions
EndCheck : function(PlayerHealth, EnemyHealth)
{
var FightOver = false;

if (EnemyHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    monsterBeat = true;
    }
else if (PlayerHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    }

if (FightOver == true)
{
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 500, y: 150 })
.text('Victory!');
}

},
});
```

Comment: ive tried to use ._x and ._y to get the values but they seem to be giving me values of 1 each (sticking my character within the game border)

Comment: I should also add I have tried using them in different locations and some would stick the character in the top right border and some would mean he did not appear atall